# Voice change in English grammar

Tags: grammar, active-voice

Change the voice: "Is this given to him by him?"

I'm confused between "Does he give him this?" and "Does he give this to him?"

Which one is the correct answer?

Comment: If you want to retain the prepositional phrase structure (*gives this to him*) rather introduce an indirect object structure (*gives him this*), then... Passive: *Is this given to him [by him]?* Active: *Does he give this to him?*

Comment: The example is pointlessly confusing simply because ***him*** is being used twice in the same sentence ***to refer to different people*** - which is so klunky native speakers would normally avoid it. Why not let the possible donor be female: *Is this given to him by **her**?*

Comment: It's a stupid exercise and you shouldn't worry about it.